# How to center textbox at the center of the screen along with three buttons at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I am working with android and I have designed my xml in which I am showing three buttons at the bottom of my screen. Now I want to show a textbox at the center of my screen along with three buttons at the bottom of the screen.

Below is my layout which shows three buttons at the bottom of the screen but it doesn't show textbox at the center of the screen -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ButtonA" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ButtonB" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ButtonC" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And also how do I add a placeholder in the textbox just like we do in HTML? As soon as I click in the testbox that placeholder will be gone and they can start typing.

Comment: Note that clarity in your post would have saved you from asking, essentially, the same question twice. I commented on your last post about using a RelativeLayout.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils : and Divyang Metalia 's answer accepted twice!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code, i think its work for you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonC" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Your Hint Here"
    android:inputType="text" >
</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Divyang. Appreciated your help. It works  fine, one minor  thing - do you know how can I add a placeholder type thing in this textbox? Something like this - http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder

Comment: It's called `android:hint`.

Comment: @user2809564 : you can reach your goal without such complexity and parenting LinearLayout inside ReleativeLayout.it's not recommended to use LinearLayout inside ReleativeLayout

Comment: @user2809564 , i updated code without LinearLayout and With place holde (android.hint).

Comment: @DivyangMetalia How do I add a spinner just below that textbox? currently it is saying as `Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at 
 least one has layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: @user2809564 i added spinner at below at edittext, show edited code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using ReleativeLayout instead then for the TextView you can set attribute named

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

, and for three buttons , set layout_alignParentBottom :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

then align other two buttons related to first.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/button3"
        android:text="ButtonA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/button3"
        android:text="ButtonB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ButtonC"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Can you provide an xml example using RelativeLayout. I always gets confused whenever I try to use RelativeLayout. It will help me  a lot if you can provide an xml using this.

Comment: @user2809564 : see the edited answer but i write it as a sample it may need some modification , hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code and sorted it out for you.
android:hint="Your Message here". can be used to add a placeholder in the textbox.

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:ems="10"
        **android:hint="@string/edit_message"**
        android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonB" />



        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonC" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`